# why require - does not load filter

Tags: filters, actions

I am using the boilerplate for WordPress plugin : https://wppb.me/

but I don't know if it's because of there coding this is happening.

What I am trying to do is use `require` and load the below code from a file.

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/partials/ggowl_template/ggowl_template_func.php';
```

if I am putting this code in the main file of the plugin it works (without require). Not sure where I am making the mistake

---

```
add_filter('template_include', 'ggowl_template_post_function',-20,1);

function ggowl_template_post_function($single) {
        //$ggowl_admin_options = get_option('ggowl_admin_options');
        // if( null !== get_option('ggowl_admin_options')){
        if( false !== get_option('ggowl_admin_options')){
            global $post;
            if( !is_object($post) ){
            return $single;
            }

            $ggowl_admin_options = get_option('ggowl_admin_options'); // Array of All Options
                $ggowl_admin_template_options = $ggowl_admin_options['ggowl_select_post_template_repeater'];
                foreach ($ggowl_admin_template_options as $key => $value) {
                    $posttype = $value[0];
                    // var_dump($posttype);
                    $ggowl_select_post_template_0 = (int)$value['template'][0][0];
                    if ( ($post->post_type == $posttype )&&($ggowl_select_post_template_0 != 0) ) {
                            if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/templates/ggowl-template-post.php' ) ) {
                                    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/templates/ggowl-template-post.php';
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    return $single;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The filter itself probably works, but the `file_exists()` returns `false`.***

So not sure if this answers the question, but one issue I see in your code is:

When you put the code in `your-plugin/admin/partials/ggowl_template/ggowl_template_func.php`, `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` from within the `ggowl_template_post_function()` would be `your-plugin/admin/partials/ggowl_template/` — and not the main plugin file path, so I suggest you to define the main plugin file (its absolute path) in the main plugin file, like so:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );
```

And from other PHP files than the main plugin file, you'd use `MY_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_FILE` and not `__FILE__` when referencing to the *main plugin file*.

Comment: Works Perfectly :). I kept thinking that the problem was with filter

Comment: Well, it worked when not being `require`d, hence the problem shouldn't be that the filter is not being applied (i.e. the callback is not being called). And if you didn't check if the template file exists, you would've seen the problem.. :)